# Magento2: How to load a product using URL key?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3

I need to load a product using its URL key. I find methods to load using only ID and SKU like,

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
$product = $this->_productRepository->get($productSku);
```

How can I achieve this using URL key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the product collection:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

...

$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', $yourUrlKey);
$product = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

Another option is to use the UrlRewrite collection (`Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewriteCollectionFactory`) to fetch the line from url_rewrite table with `request_path = $yourUrlKey` and `entity_type='product'`. There, you will find the desired entity_id of the product and you can simply load it.